# anchor tag in not making div clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make a whole div clickable, i did the following

```html
  <a href=""><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 item-mb">
                        <div class="service-box1 bg-body text-center">
                            <img src="img/service/service1.png" alt="service" class="img-fluid">
                            <h3 class="title-medium-dark mb-none"><a href="category-list-layout1.html">Electronics</a></h3>
                            <div class="view">(19,805)</div>
                        </div>
                    </div></a>
```

but he div is not becoming clickable, can anyone please tell me whats wrong in my code?

Comment: you need something in the href and you cannot have nested anchors

Comment: you cannot have a tag again inside a tag .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 item-mb" onClick="javascript:window.location='//stackoverflow.com'">
  <div class="service-box1 bg-body text-center">
    <img src="img/service/service1.png" alt="service" class="img-fluid">
    <h3 class="title-medium-dark mb-none"><a href="category-list-layout1.html">Electronics</a></h3>
    <div class="view">(19,805)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: used some different thing onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor: pointer;", anyway you gave the idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, in the code below I created a function that adds `click` event handlers instead of using `a` tags which can't be put inside each other.

Also included an example of how to style the div (see `clickable` css class).

```js
function addLink(divId, url){
    let div = document.getElementById(divId);
    div.setAttribute('data-link-url', url);
    link1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        window.location = this.getAttribute('data-link-url');
    });
}

addLink('link1', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
```

```css
.clickable{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="link1" class="clickable">
    <div class="service-box1 bg-body text-center">
        <img src="img/service/service1.png" alt="service" class="img-fluid">
        <h3 class="title-medium-dark mb-none">text</h3>
        <div class="view">(19,805)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve? Do you want the whole div to link to the same place or do you need the inner link to send the user somewhere else?

Comment: then adapt the styling. if you can't solve it open another question

Comment: same place, but when i remove the inner link, the style is getting wrong

Comment: @TEIA2019, then just fix your styles

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have a `div` inside `a`. I mean, technically in some environments it works, but its against specification, so you can't rely on that structure. If you want to have a `div` wide link you better have your `a` absolutely positioned and stretched to fit your `div`

Comment: but i have heard in latest version of html we can use div inside anchor tag